# Android mp4parser - create Track from Bitmap

Tags: android, video, bitmap, mp4, mp4parser

How to have a video Track from an image (Bitmap) on Android?

I need to add an image at end of my video.. for 5 seconds

Thanks

Comment: You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: I'm asking without code because i have nothing to show. I'm blind right now

Comment: That is the problem, YOU need to do the research and the work, we are here to help you with errors or trouble you run into. Not to teach you from start to finish, or do the work for you. You aren't new to the site, you should know better.

Comment: I'm looking for this from 3 days and nothing found

Comment: There we go, I provided you with some keywords to help with future searches (I know, getting the right terminology to search with can be the real trick). Also, its not uncommon for some systems to require you to do what I described. Encoding images AS videos makes them integrate with these systems easier than going from streaming/bufferable content to static content.

Comment: Did you have any luck @Tiziano?

Comment: Yes finally! I've finally done with JCodec library
http://jcodec.org/
Thank you for help!

Comment: Cool man! You can answer your own question and accept it so the community knows there is a good answer. Just be sure to provide a full and detailed description, as outlined on the [how to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page. You could also toss me an upvote ;) and then I can actually take this question out of the negative too.

Answer (score 0):

The terminology for what comes after a video is called a "Post Roll" (or before a video, "Pre Roll"). This will help you in future searching.

If you are attempting to use an Image as your Post Roll, this will not work [as it says at the very bottom of their GitHub page](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser).

**So what can you do?**

As they also say on that page, you can "Append Recordings with Same Encode Settings". So you can encode your image as a video with the:

- SAME resolutions
- SAME frame-rates

as your main video, then they will chain properly.